# User permissions for displaying iAds for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

In my application i created an iAd. I am having one doubt,is it necessary to ask user permissions for displaying iAds before loading the screen.

Comment: It would be exceptionally polite of you. It might gain you some friendly customers, and you could leave it an option in the settings to turn them back on. Best case if they are not all the time in users face, and not near to important buttons in game or menu, to avoid mistaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not in any way obligated to ask the user for permission to display ads. Think about if you did this, every user would select not to show them, and then you wouldn't make any money (the point of an ad!)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.This is very valuable to me.

Comment: Well considering me and @meronix gave you similar responses at basically the same time, (I think he beat me) please choose which ever response you feel helped you the most and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: ok.I am new to this one.Can you tell me one thing for Standard banner how long will they be displayed on screen.

Comment: Sure, once your app has been loaded and the iAd appears, the iAd server will continuously push new ads to it until your app closes.

Comment: yes the server will do like that. If the user tapped on the iAd the ad will display on the full screen. Otherwise i want to close the banner and reload the banner after 10 seconds.Can you tell me how to approach it.

Comment: Apple may frown upon this, but implementation would be pretty simple, do a google search for using a NSTimer. You could easily configure this to release the add banner after 10 seconds and reload a new one. But as a said above, I don't know how apple will feel about this considering this constant refresh would be essentially cheating the ad system and making you more money than they want to pay you.

Answer (score 1):

not at all.

just keep in mind that users may not like AD banner displayed in NOT-FREE app...